# View that displays map with clustered points and Streetview option

Tags: 7, views, location, google-maps

I need to construct a map block that displays multiple location markers with the following characteristics:

1. Markers are linked to other content on the page.
2. Markers are clustered until you zoom in far enough, when they gradually resolve into separate markers.
3. Individual locations may have multiple markers leading to different content on the page.
4. It's possible to open the map in a full-screen view.
5. It's possible to display the map in satellite view.
6. It's possible to switch to Google StreetView by dropping the orange pegman onto the map. I do not need to display a panorama of the locations, just have the orange pegman available.

I have the following relevant modules installed:

- Geofield
- IP Geolocation Views & Maps
- Leaflet
- Leaflet Markercluster
- Leaflet More Maps
- Leaflet Views

but I'm willing to supplement these or switch them to get the right functionality.

At present I can **either**:

1. construct a map that handles the markers as I wish on a Google hi res map (using a Map view generated using Leaflet API via IPGV&M). I believe I will be able to add full screen capability to this as well, but haven't tested it yet. Satellite view works. *I have not found a way to provide Google Streetview in this set up.*

**or**

2. construct a map that has full-screen capability and Streetview and satellite view on a Google his res map (view generated using Google API via IPGV&M). *However, markers aren't clustered and only a single marker is associated with each location which means I can't link to all the appropriate content on the page*.

What can I do to meet the full set of requirements? Is it possible to add Streetview capability to the Leaflet API solution? Or Marker clustering to the Google API solution?

I've reviewed https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/70636/incorporate-google-streetview-into-a-leaflet-map and the linked questions there, but haven't found a solution; not have I found a solution in the [location] tag here.